# How can I open multiple files one after the other with python?

Tags: python

With python I want to:

- open a file
- do some stuff to it
- close it (if necessary)
- open another
- repeat

Currently my approach would be:

```
for f in args.files:
    print(f)
    bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=f)
```

which throws an error `RuntimeError: Error: File written by newer Blender binary (300.42), expect loss of data!` but only at the second file. Everything works of if that same file is the first of the list, so I suspect that I am missing some kind of "close a file before opening another" operation.

How can I do that?

Comment: maybe you're working on blender 3.x files with an older version like 2.8..?

Comment: @calambre - that doesn't seem to be the issue, as the first file gets processed without issue

Comment: oh yes, you mentioned that, sorry... so you mean opening many files from a blender instance? not that easy I think, the time you open a new file that instance is gone, I think you need a persistent handler to remain in memory as you close and open them... never tried it myself, what I've done is opened a blend -or a batch- from command line and tell it to run an external script, it should be a lot easier to do I think

Comment: @calambre - yes, using a script (find/exec on linux) is what I did mostly, but that's less portable across linux and windows, so I was hoping fos something fully Blender-based